# Windows Service use Oracle 32bit Client instead of 64bit

Tags: windows, oracle, service, 32bit-64bit

Installed is only Oracle Database 64bit (12.1.0)
All is fine, my program (App1) (compiled as "Any CPU") runs and can connect (gui and as a windows service) to any Oracle database. Program and windows service run as 64bit.

Because of an other program (App2), i installed Oracle Client 32bit (12.1.0). This program runs, all fine (32bit).
App1 runs also good, if i connect to Oracle over the gui (still 64bit).
But if i run the windows service on App1, it occurs this exception

> Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This >problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client >components installed.
>   Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.

I don't understand why this exception occurs! Has anyone an idea?

I tried this here, without success: [Installing Oracle 32-bit Client on Windows Server Already Running 64-bit Oracle Database Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle)

On an other machine, i installed the Oracle client first, and then the database. Surprisingly, no exception if i run the windows service!

Is anywhere defined (a path, or what ever) which oracle version a windows service has to use?

At the moment, it's not an option to implement an oracle dll in my apps.

### PATH values:

```
C:\Users\test>dir /al %windir%\System32

 Verzeichnis von C:\Windows\System32

20.06.2017  13:04    <SYMLINKD>     ora121 [C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1]

           0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
           1 Verzeichnis(se), 505'220'648'960 Bytes frei

C:\Users\test>dir /al %windir%\SysWOW64

 Verzeichnis von C:\Windows\SysWOW64

20.06.2017  13:04    <SYMLINKD>     ora121 [C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1]
           0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
           1 Verzeichnis(se), 505'220'648'960 Bytes frei
```

Comment: Did you carefully follow instruction your refer to? Have also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client for proper remove old Oracle Client.

Comment: nearly, i had the path to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ora112 in the environment variable PATH. i removed it now, and it get this error: "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater"
someone said this is a right problem, but not here, i get all rights for all users and the exception is still here.

Comment: Did you create the symbolic links? Please post the entire PATH value. What do you get from `dir /al %windir%\System32` and `dir /al %windir%\SysWOW64`?

Comment: yes

C:\Users\test>dir /al %windir%\System32
 Verzeichnis von C:\Windows\System32
20.06.2017  13:04    <SYMLINKD>     ora121 [C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1]

C:\Users\test>dir /al %windir%\SysWOW64
 Verzeichnis von C:\Windows\SysWOW64
20.06.2017  13:04    <SYMLINKD>     ora121 [C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1]

Comment: Better edit your question and put result there.

Comment: ok, see in the question

Comment: Let's discuss in a chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60761/oracle-32-64-bit-installation

Comment: to chat it needs 20 reputation, i don't have so many :-(

Comment: Read some https://meta.stackexchange.com/ or other stackoverflow documentations.

Comment: i don't understand what it benefits, when i read some articles or documentations. i get reputations by ask and answer questions, or how many articles have i to read?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it with Badges. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work for how getting reputation.

Comment: ok. i don't have an additional question, and write answer is not so my power. but i saw, if anyone upvote my question i get 5 rep right? next problem, i know nobody how has enough to vote :-(
could you resume that, that would be awesome?

Comment: Can you access now?

Comment: Yes, perfect, thx

Comment: Ok, I am also in