# Installed Oracle 64-Bit before 32-Bit driver

Tags: oracle, driver

I installed Oracle 64-bit driver before the 32-bit driver that I need for my application. Now I am getting a missing driver connection error when I am using my 32-bit application. I tried reinstalling the 32-bit driver to no avail. Is there anything I need to change in the registry to make sure oracle uses the 32-bit driver and not the 64?

Comment: Follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle/25229914#25229914 Remove any existing installation before you start this, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go.