# When both 32-bit and 64-bit oracle client installed in the same 64-bit widows 10, Crystal Reports XI not working

Tags: database, oracle, 64-bit, 32-bit, crystal-reports-xi

I need to connect to Oracle11g database using PowerBI (64-bit) and crystal reports xi (32-bit). I installed both versions of Oracle client following the instruction provided in this thread [Installing Oracle 32-bit Client on Windows Server Already Running 64-bit Oracle Database Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle/25229914)

PowerBI is working well and Crystal reports xi can't connect to Oracle database. The error message is "unknown database connector error".

Since the crystal reports xi is a 32-bit version, I checked ODBC data source administrator (32-bit). It is unable to connect SQLState= IM004, see the screenshot below. Is that the reason Crystal reports not connecting?
[IM004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm2kR.jpg)

I also noticed the trusted_connection is false in crystal reports (see screenshot), not sure if that is another problem.

[TRUST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA3Hk.jpg)

Any idea of why Crystal Reports can't connect to the Oracle database?

Comment: When you install the Oracle Client did you also install the ODBC drivers? (32 and 64 bit)

Comment: Try to add DSN as "System DSN". As far as I know "User DSN" does not distinct between 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, I have both 32 and 64 bit ODBC drivers. I can't add system DSN in the 32 bit odbc data source administrator. I added system DSN in the 64 bit odbc data source administrator. Stil getting "unknow database connector error" in 32 bit Crystal Reports when trying to refresh reports.