# Oracle XE 64 Bit ODBC connection with 32 bit c# application

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I created a C# Windows Form Application(32Bit) using visual studio 2015 and dotNet Framework 4.
I want that client can connect his database using odbc dsn , whether it's a 32bit OS or 64bit OS.
on 32 bit OS , it's working fine, but on 64bit OS , it's not working, since oracle XE 64 bit is installed.

**More details**
The Application can connect to any datasource using ODBC.The problem is comming when application is trying to connect oracle XE (64bit) installed on local system of the client,because in case of 32 bit everything works fine. So anything additional needs to be installed on the system so that 32 bit application can connect to oracle XE (64) installed on client machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is not much you can do about this. The ODBC driver is either 32-bit or 64-bit and it has to match the architecture (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) of your application.
The Oracle client has to be also in the same architecture.

I see three solutions:

- You provide two versions of your application. One 32-bit version and one 64-bit version. Many application around the world are provided in this two options.
- Create a 32-bit application with 32-bit ODBC driver. Such 32-bit application works also on a 64-bit Windows without any problem. 64-bit Windows supports 32-bit and 64-bit applications.
- Use the [ODP.NET Managed Driver](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html). This works for both, 32-bit and 64-bit. However, it does not utilize the ODBC DSN

If you like to be independent you can install both Oracle Clients, 32-bit and 64-bit on one machine. Follow [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100).

Comment: Is there any way, that I can provide 32 bit of the application , and provide client with 32 bit oracle odbc driver, so that he can connect to oracle 64 bit XE ?

Comment: This does not matter. A 32-bit Client can connect to any database, no matter if the database is 32-bit or 64-bit. Of course, also the 64-bit Client can connect to any database. Only the Oracle Client, the ODBC driver and your application have to be all the same.

Comment: Client already have oracle XE installed on his system ( 64bit ) , does it includes oracle client ? what else needs to be installed on client system ? On 32 bit everything works fine

Comment: Yes, the database includes always the client (but perhaps the ODBC driver is not installed, needs to be checked). Anyway, you have mixed architectures thus the customer must install 32-bit Client on top following the instruction I provided in my answer. The same topic was already addressed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle/25229914#25229914 (with the same solution)

Comment: The method is a bit confusing for me , as I haven't worked on oracle. Oracle XE is already installed ( x64 ), so dont know if oracle client is already installed or not .
Can you please guide me using my scenario ?

Comment: Yes it is. However "Oracle Client" are just some core DLL's. There are many components you can install on top of it, e.g. the ODBC driver which is by default not part of the Client installation. Apart from that the 32-bit world is completely separated from the 64-bit world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183497/discussion-between-mohd-qasim-and-wernfried-domscheit).