# SSIS visual studio 2015 oracle - Bad

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis

Having issues connecting to Oracle (12c) using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 on Windows 10. I get the following error when testing the connection.

[image]

I need to connect using the .Net Providers and looking for advice/guidance on how to resolve the 32/64 bit issue.

I have followed this article [Installing Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT150) and have managed to unzip the contents of the file to the c:\oracle directory and ran the batch file with the following parameters:

install_odpm.bat c:\oracle both false

The installation appears to run successfully, however, I still get the error in VS 2015.

I mostly use SQL server so not much experience troubleshooting Oracle connections.Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Which Oracle did you install? The 32-bit bit or the 64-bit version? In which mode is your application running?

Comment: I **assume** `.Net Providers\OracleClient Data Provider` is the [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?view=netframework-4.8) "Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle". Which other provides are offered in the connection wizard?

Comment: Thank for your response Wernfried, This package is already in production, so had to use the exact same providers. I managed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve the issue. I followed these steps and it worked:

1. Download and install both 32 and 64 bit clients from [Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle12c-windows-downloads.html)
2. Download and install [ODAC for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/dotnet-odacmsi-downloads.html)

Make sure visual studio 2015 is closed in the process.

Comment: If you made the simple installation then it works only by coincidence, actually you messed up your Oracle installation. If you like to install (and use) 32-bit and 64-bit drivers together follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle/25229914#25229914

Comment: You should install only **one** Oracle Client, i.e. one each for 32-bit and 64-bit. I am quite sure, if you try other connection types (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999) then some of them will fail.