# Which version of Oracle ODAC is compatible with 10.2 database and can be installed on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: oracle, oledb, oraoledb

I have Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 database installed on a OpenVMS server.

I wrote some ASP.Net MVC apps to read and write to the database.
The development machine was Windows 7 32bit. I had Oracle Client installed.
The apps rely on Oracle OleDB Provider.

The apps should be hosted on Windows Server 2019.

When I set up the apps in the new IIS, I get the error about missing OraOLEDB Provider.

I tried to install ODAC122010Xcopy_x64 using the command
`install oledb c:\oracle\home1 home1`

the command ended with no errors. But the list of providers were not affected. The same error was reported even after restarting the machine.

I then tried:
`install all c:\oracle\home1 home1` but with no difference.

Is it a prerequirement to install Oracle Client on the server?
If so, which version will work best for Windows Server 2019?

If not, then what version of ODAC is supported by the server?

Comment: Why do you run an outdated version of Oracle database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image: Support Matrix]

You need an Oracle client version 12.1 or older.

Yes, the OraOLEDB Provider requires an Oracle client and the version of both must be **exactly** the same.

The architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) must also match. When the application was developed on a 32-bit Windows, then you must install the 32-bit version of Oracle Client and OraOLEDB Provider.

If required, you can install both a 32-bit and a 64-bit Oracle client, see [Installing Oracle 32-bit Client on Windows Server Already Running 64-bit Oracle Database Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216290/installing-oracle-32-bit-client-on-windows-server-already-running-64-bit-oracle/25229914#25229914)

Be aware, due to Windows COM limitation you can install only **one** OraOLEDB Provider (i.e. one each for 32-bit and 64-bit).